Is Ezekiel 33:10-20 relevant to the contemporary Church, and what are its theological implications for soteriology?
God says that a righteous person who sins will not be saved by their past righteousness. Conversely, if a wicked person repents and turns from their sins, they will live and not be punished for their past wickedness.
Is there a doctrinal disparity in the salvation of saints in the Old Testament and the New Testament?
How do the themes of repentance and accountability in Ezekiel 33:10-20 align with the teachings of repentance in the New Testament?

They are the same - there is only ONE way to be saved - have faith in Jesus as Messiah

Yes, the themes of repentance and accountability in Ezekiel 33:10-20 align with the teachings of repentance and accountability in the New Testament. This is clearly shown in the way Jesus dealt with repentant Zacchaeus.
This dishonest tax-collector desperately wanted to see Jesus when he came through Jericho, but Jesus saw him and called him down from the tree he had climbed. The result was Zacchaeus not only repenting before Jesus but promising to give half his goods to the poor, and to restore four-fold what he had dishonestly gained - more than what the law required. Jesus rejoiced and said,

"This day is salvation come to this house, forsomuch as he also is a
son of Abraham." Luke 19:1-9 K.J.V.

This exemplifies the outworking of Ezekiel 33:10-20. This is particularly clear with this translation's points regarding verses 14-16:

"And in My saying to the wicked; Thou surely diest, And - He hath
turned back from his sin, And hath done judgment and righteousness.
(The pledge the wicked restoreth, plunder he repayeth.) In the
statutes opf life he hath walketh, So as not to do perversity. He
surely liveth - he doth not die. None of his sin that he hath sinned
is remembered to him. Judgment and righteousness he hath done. He doth
surely live." Ezekiel 33:14-16 Y.L.T.

Recall what John the Baptist's message was to all coming to him for baptism. He exhorted them to keep the law regarding the poor etc. To tax collectors who enquired what they should do he said, "Exact no more than that directed you." Zacchaeus made restitution for his over-charging, plus gave to the poor. Could it be that he had been one of those tax-collectors, and so was prepared for the Messiah coming, repentantly receiving Christ with a whole heart?
Yet the New Testament had to record Jesus' finished work on the cross, and his resurrection, before the full impact of salvation dawned on the Jewish people who, like Zacchaeus, 'received' Christ in faith. John was the last and greatest of the Old Testament prophets; when the Kingdom of God was then 'seen' in Christ as its King, repentance and salvation was fully understood, soteriology became a core foundation of the Christian church, to this very day.
There is no doctrinal disparity between what the Old Testament says about salvation, and what the New Testament says. Properly understanding how God's covenant people were to live in light of God's promises of forgiveness and salvation to the repentant who forsook their wicked ways is vital for then grasping the same need of repentance and forsaking wickedness from Christ's time on. It's just that now we see that only what Christ did on the cross, by his shed blood, will achieve God's total free pardon for those repentantly putting total faith in what he did.
And those "who get it" simply use legal requirements as a spring-board from which to leap into generosity of spirit, giving, and serving, as subjects of God's Kingdom and who, as ambassadors for Christ, urge others to be reconciled to God through the faith of Christ (2 Corinthians 5:20).

I guess it's interesting that Ezekiel's words say quite plainly that G-d will forgive those who repent, and no where in sight is the concept of a god-man needed for intercession

@AviAvraham  Yes, repentance and forgiveness in the Hebrew scriptures is clearly there, with the blood sacrifices of animals showing that blood must be shed, "for the life is in the blood". And, "Without the shedding of blood, there is no forgiveness of sins." God is Spirit; so Christians understand that the Son of God agreed to leave heaven to have human nature added to his divine nature, in order to shed his blood. Thus the righteousness of God in punishing sin (past, present, future of all having faith) was displayed at the cross, and, once punished, removed. You may not agree, of course.
